# Is virtual defining a smart function pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

In my understanding, the virtual is kind of like a samrt funtion pointer when switching between derived classes. Is there any better understanding to illustrate "virtual" comparing to the "real function"?

Comment: The most common way to implement virtual functions is by using a *table* (an array) of pointers to functions. Each element in the table points to the specific implementation of the function in the object. Many good books and tutorials have images depicting this relationship, but if you want more details you have to be asking a much more focused question about the specific single detail you wonder about (this isn't really a tutorial site).

Comment: No, `virtual` does not define a smart function pointer. If a function is declared `virtual` by a base class, then derived classes can override it. Users, given a pointer or reference to the base class, can call the virtual function and - if the pointer/reference actually refers to an instance of a derived class - calls the most derived version. This has names such as "dynamic dispatch".  A smart pointer is something completely different, and C++ has no such thing as a "smart function pointer".  Making up your own language to describe this will simply confuse anyone else you talk with.

Answer (score 0):

What you called `samrt funtion pointer` is `Dynamic dispatch` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). The typical method to implement `Dynamic dispatch`  is called `vurtual method table` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)